# Launching Sublime Text 2 from Terminal (Mac OS El Capitan)

Tags: macos, command-line, sublimetext2, sublimetext, osx-elcapitan

I've looked all over Stack Overflow and everyone's had their problem solved. I just can't get any of the solutions to work on my Mac.

I've tried `sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin`, `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`, and my terminal says:

```
mkdir: /usr/local: No such file or directory
mkdir: /usr/local/bin: Operation not permitted
```

When I `cd /usr`, and `ls` it shows me these files:

```
X11
adic
lib
sbin
standalone
X11R6
bin
libexec
share
```

Was there supposed to be a `local` folder inside the `usr` folder?

Either way, I can't create any directories inside the `usr` or `usr/bin` folders or even use the `ls`. Why is this happening? Is there a way to force the terminal to create a directory?

I'm also new and trying to get the grasp of how Terminal really works...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) some time, as it appears you are struggling to get your formatting right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't upgraded to El Capitán, partially for this reason, but putting the `subl` symlink in `~/bin` will work for any version of OS X. First, though, I **strongly** recommend using [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3). Even though it's called "beta", it's rock solid and has *many* feature additions, improvements, and bug fixes over ST2. I've been using it exclusively for over 2 years now, and I wouldn't dream of going back.

1. In your home directory, create a `bin` directory (`$` is the terminal prompt, don't type it):

   ```
   $ cd
   $ mkdir bin
   ```
2. Create the symlink. If you use ST3, this is the proper command. Otherwise, add `\ 2` between `Text` and `.app`:

   ```
   $ ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ~/bin/subl
   ```
3. Either open or create `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` (if you already have one, use that. Otherwise, use `.profile`):

   ```
   $ bin/subl .profile
   ```
4. Add the following to it (it really doesn't matter where in the file you put it):

   ```
   export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```

Save the file, restart your Terminal session, and the `subl` command should now be available.

---

Based on your comments, I suspect that `Sublime Text.app` may actually be in your `/Users/username/Applications` directory instead of `/Applications`. Try running the following commands to test this:

```sh
$ cd
$ rm bin/subl
$ ln -s /Users/username/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl $HOME/bin/subl
# where username is your actual user name
$ bin/subl .bashrc
```

If Sublime opens with either an actual `.bashrc` or an empty file, then you're good to go — you can add the `export PATH=...` command as above and save the file. Keep in mind that the path for the `ln` command is assuming you're using Sublime Text 3, as recommended.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it... I did these steps, but I had to `source .profile` before I could use the `subl` command. It worked, but I just have two more question... Should I go to Terminal's preferences and make it launch with the `source .profile` right away? And can I add more commands to the `.profile` I created, or would that conflict with the path I had for the sublime? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @happycrappie what shell are you using? `~/.profile` should automatically be sourced. If it's not, try renaming it to `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`: `mv .profile .bashrc` should do it. You can add as many commands to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` as you want - it's just a shell script that gets executed with a login shell. Mine is currently 101 lines long...

Comment: Idk what shell... I suppose it's the standard one (I'm new to this whole Terminal, but I'm trying to get the grasp of it). Anytime I try to `ln` something in a `˜/folder`, it does not allow me. It shows the following: `$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ˜/bin/subl
Password:
ln: ˜/bin/subl: No such file or directory` even when I `sudo` it.

Comment: @happycrappie What is the result of `ls ~/bin`?

Comment: `$ ls ˜/bin
ls: ˜/bin: No such file or directory`
It seems as if `˜` does not exist on my Mac. Everybody uses `˜/folder`, it just doesn't exist/work as the home directory...

Comment: @happycrappie so this is **after** running `mkdir bin` in your home directory? That's not good. At any rate, for the time being replace `~` with `$HOME` in step 2 above, then go through it again and let me know if it works.

Comment: @happycrappie by the way, what does your prompt look like?

Comment: `iMac-de-Eryc:~ Eryc$ ls` 
`Applications Downloads Movies  Public
Desktop  Dropbox  Music  Sites
Documents Library  Pictures bin`
I'm accessing from my User folder, I think. I tried to `cd $HOME`, and it puts me back into my User folder. I created the `bin/subl`, but still can't create the `profile`... 
`Eryc$ ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl $HOME/bin/subl
ln: /Users/Eryc/bin/subl: File exists` The file exists in the `$HOME/bin/subl`, I'm just not allowed to create a .profile `Eryc$ bin/subl .profile
-bash: bin/subl: No such file or directory`

Comment: Apparently I have 2 Applications folders, one inside of my Users folder, and another that's in the root(?) HD. I can access the `/Users/Eryc/Applications` folder through the Terminal app, I just can't access it from the root. I don't even think I'm allowed on the root within my terminal right now. It shows `iMac-de-Eryc:˜ Eryc$` and when I `cd ˜/`, it shows this: `-bash: cd: ˜/: No such file or directory` So I guess the issue really is accessing my HD or root, or however it is called... Keeping in mind I'm running El Capitain - that is rootless, like @imvelox mentioned.

Comment: @happycrappie I'm really not sure what's going on. As I mentioned in the original answer, I haven't upgraded to El Capitan, as I'm quite happy with Yosemite at the moment, and issues like this that I've heard about make me rather leery. At any rate, see my edit above to check if that solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what's going on, and it may have something to do with El Capitain. I did all the steps, but when I go to `bin/subl .bashrc` or `.profile`, it doesn't let me. Says "No such file or directory". It's weird because it is there! I just can't access it... I've downloaded iTerm and can't `git clone` as well. I'll look further into it, or I might just format my Mac (I was wanting to do this for awhile) and then see what happens.

Comment: @happycrappie You are pasting stuff in comments here using the "small tilde" unicode character, which your shell will not recognize as home. You need to use the regular ASCII tilde for that (`~`, ASCII 0x7e) instead of the one you are using (`˜`, UTF-8 0xcb9c).

Comment: @happycrappie based on Dan Lowe's observation, you must be using some incorrect encoding, and entering characters that are not standard ASCII.

Comment: @DanLowe @MattDMo that's exactly the issue. I was trying to type it myself so I would learn better, instead of just copying and pasting. I just copied and pasted all of Matt's solutions and it worked. I just changed from `bash` to `zsh` and I pasted the `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` to the `.zshrc` and it works just fine now on my iTerm. I fixed this creating a shortcut on `iTerm > Preferences > Keys > +` to `⌥+n` send hex codes: `0x7e` and added `export LANG=en_US.ASCII` to the `.zshrc`. Thank you guys so much.

Comment: @happycrappie No problem, glad to help. I would actually change the encoding to `en_US.UTF-8` so you don't run into issues later with Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

If `/usr/local` doesn't exist, trying to create `/usr/local/bin` will fail because there is nowhere to put it. You can either create `/usr/local` first, or use the `-p` flag to mkdir, which will create any missing directories in the path automatically.

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

The answer pointing to El Capitan's rootless mode is **not correct**. Four locations are not restricted by rootless mode.

```
/usr/local
/Applications
/Library
~/Library
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and all attempts at creating, removing and recreating the symlink didn't work even though my `$PATH` variable and `~/.bash_profile` content looked as expected. What eventually worked for me was to remove the space from the actual Sublime installation directory (`/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`) and running the symlink creation as

```
$ ln -s /Applications/SublimeText.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ~/bin/subl
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because of El Capitan's new *rootless* system: basically root can't access system directories anymore.

To disable this, follow this:
[Disabling rootless mode on El Capitan](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11)

Comment: I was reading about it and most people think it's not a good idea to disable the `csrutil`. Is there any other way, like creating a `bash_profile`, for an example?

Comment: rootless mode does not restrict `/usr/local`. It is specifically called out in their WWDC session on this topic as an allowed location that is not restricted by rootless mode. But if it doesn't exist you can't create directories under it.